Netbeans not showing index of directory instead of content of html file in browser
I have installed AMPPS and Netbeans on my Windows 11 notebook.
If I run my file "helloworld.html"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>A quick test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
  </body>
</html>

in the directory for the local host (c:/programs/ampps/www), Netbeans shows me in the browser the index of the directory of the local host, but not the "Hello world!" html page.
In the httpd.conf of Apache Server I have:
  Listen 80

In the project settings I have set the browser to "IDE's default server".
In the launch.json I have the following (automatically written code):
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch built-in server and debug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-S",
                "localhost",
                "-t",
                "."
            ],
            "port": 80,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug current script in console",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
} 

